# Automatically naming and choosing dependency file

Tags: makefile

In the following makefile snippet:

```
common.o :
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF "$@.d" -c miwt_os/dispatcher/common.cpp
-include commono.o.d

array_safe.o :
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF "$@.d" -c miwt_os/dispatcher/array_safe.cpp
-include array_safe.o.d

tstamp.o :
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF "$@.d" -c miwt_os/dispatcher/tstamp.cpp
-include tstamp.o.d

cbor_encoder.o :
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF "$@.d" -c miwt_os/coap/cbor_encoder.cpp
-include cbor_encoder.o.d

cbor_encoder_test.o : 
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF "$@.d" -c miwt_os/coap/unittest/cbor_encoder_test.cpp
-include cbor_encoder_test.o.d

cbor_encoder_test : array_safe.o tstamp.o cbor_encoder_test.o cbor_encoder.o \
                    common.o gmock_main.a
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -lpthread $^ -o $@
```

Notice how the dependency file name is auto-generated by "$@.d", but then when it is included, I have to manually enter the name of dependency the file.  Any way to automatically generate the dependency file name?

Comment: you could output all your .d's to a specific directory include `dir/*.d`

Answer (score 2):

If you had a variable containing the list of object files, instead of inlining them, then it would be trivial:

```
OBJS = array_safe.o tstamp.o cbor_encoder_test.o cbor_encoder.o common.o

-include $(addsuffix .d,$(OBJS))

cbor_encoder_test : $(OBJS) gmock_main.a
        ...
```

I should point out that this method of dealing with auto-generated header files is suboptimal; there are [better ways](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/).